# How can I use variable grabbed from JAVA server to my Angular App?

Tags: java, angular, jsp, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I'm grabbing various infos (email adress, name, profile picture URL) from sign in and don't really know how to integrate them a proper way to my Angular App.

I though of various methods

1. adding a scriptlet to the main `index.html` file. but that doesn't really seems the best way to take advantage of data binding and the data will be out of my Angular App scope.So that definetly limits the usages
2. add an input to my selector and do something like `<my-selector[email]="${sessionScope.sessionUser.email}"></my-selector>`. And pass it to the child components but that would potentially make be do a lot of inputs and outputs, still hope there would be a better approach.Also I'm not sure this would work with router outlet.
3. Initialize the data into a service but files are compiled plus even if I find where I can change the variable I don't know if I can add scriptlets to javascript files.
4. pass infos with another `GET` request. so this will do "2" `GET` requests, one on accessing the page and one when initialising a `UserService` for example. So far this is the best solution I've though about.

Any other solution or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just create a service and store the value there?  If the service is declared in the app module then the value will be accessible to all consumers of that service and the value will remain as long as the app is not refreshed.  Of course, you could just use local storage as well..

Comment: @QuietSeditionist so for the service as I told in point number 3 since then I've checked and I can easily find the variable inside my main.js but can I add scriptlets to my js file? I use two server with a proxy redirection so this seems really painful to serve then when it works then build then add scriptlets to static html//js files. For dev I though the could be a better solution. Now for local storage any quick example as answer will be greatly appreciated I'll upvote of course but not sure to mark it as answered. Many thanks